# In dash app, my custom css file does not work when app starts

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

I am developping dash app in python.

To use my custom css file, I followed the recommended structure between app.py and assets folder.

However, it does not work when app start.

To apply it to my app, I have to go to custom.css and ctrl+s (save actual state)

**Structure**

```
- app.py
- assets/
    |-- custom.css
```

**code**

```
external_style = [dbc.themes.MATERIA,dbc.icons.FONT_AWESOME]
appDash = dash.Dash(__name__,
                # Do not show exceptions
                suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
                # Use specific CSS to make your application looks wonderful
                external_stylesheets=external_style,
                
                url_base_pathname='/my_super_app/',
                # use_pages=True
                # Web application name
                    # Title []
                )
```

I think there is some conflict with external_style = [dbc.themes.MATERIA,dbc.icons.FONT_AWESOME]

But it does not work when I did :
external_style = [dbc.themes.MATERIA,dbc.icons.FONT_AWESOME,'path_to_custom_css']

Can you help me ?